# can i optimise this code more? What is wrong with my background worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
    every 1.minute do
      runner "DailyNotificationChecker.send_notifications"
    end
```

this is whenever gem scheduler

```
    class DailyNotificationChecker

     def self.send_notifications
            puts "Triggered send_notifications"
            expiry_time = Time.now + 57
            while (Time.now < expiry_time)
                if RUN_SCHEDULER == "true" || RUN_SCHEDULER == true
                  process_notes
                end
              sleep 4 #seconds
            end
          end

          def self.process_notes
            notes = nil
            time = Benchmark.measure do
              Note.uncached do
                notes = Note.within_2_mins.unprocessed
                if notes.present?
                  note_ids = notes.pluck(:id)
                  note_hash = {}
                  note_hash[:note_ids] = note_ids.to_json
                  url = URI.parse(PROCESS_NOTE_API_URL)
                  resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, note_hash)
                  notes.each do |note|
                     puts "note_id = #{note.id}"
                     puts "processed #{note.processed}"
                    RealtimeNotificationChecker.perform_async(note.user_id,"note_created","TempUserNote",note.id)
                  end
                end
              end
            end
              puts "time #{time}"
          end
end
```

My purpose is I am trying to run realtime notifications. If a user creates a note in app then within 4 seconds I will send him a push notification.

so I run a cron job every 1 minute and hit the method `send_notifications` in my `DailyNotificationChecker` class. Now this is supposed to run a method process_notes every 4 seconds. every new note that is created is set processed = 0 flag. and I retrieve every unprocessed flag not more than 2 mins old and perform my operation on it.

the line

```
note_ids = notes.pluck(:id)
 note_hash = {}
 note_hash[:note_ids] = note_ids.to_json
 url = URI.parse(PROCESS_NOTE_API_URL)
 resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, note_hash)
```

gets all the note_ids that are unprocessed and sends them to master server to mark them processed = 1 so that in next 4 second hit these notes dont come again to processing list.

Then I loop in every note and send them in background to send push notificaion

```
    notes.each do |note|
      RealtimeNotificationChecker.perform_async(note.user_id,"note_created","TempUserNote",note.id)
    end
```

but i guess something is wrong here. As when I have more than 2 notes in to be processed it doesn't sends notification to all users.

Can someone suggest whats wrong and required

Note:
I may have more than 10-15 notes to be processed within 4 sec.
I am using sucker punch gem for background jobs.

Comment: did you consider "pusher" for the realtime notifications, by using this you don't need to run the cron job every 1 minute.

Comment: `Can someone suggest whats wrong ....` makes this **off-topic** on Code Review

Comment: Then what needs to happen is the "what's wrong' part needs to be rewritten to match the usual Stack Overflow guidelines, and the part where the author is asking for the code to be optimised removed from here (and possibly moved over to there if it's still wanted). :) TBH even if the title is updated to describe the problem, it'll be a good start ;)